# How do I create a table with a TD aligned to the left and its sibling aligned to the right?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a table in HTML with exactly one row (tr) and two columns (td).

The first td, I want its contents aligned to the left and the second td, I want its contents aligned to the right.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tr td{text-align:right}
tr td:first-child{text-align:left}
```

But you could probably also use a th and a td instead of 2 td's.

Answer (score 1):

There are obviously several ways of doing this, but in CSS3 you have two options that I believe are more specific to what you're asking.

The Adjacent Sibling Selector

```
td { text-align: left; }
td + td { text-align: right; }
```

and the General Sibling Combinator

```
td { text-align: left; }
td ~ td { text-align: right; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `text-align` property in the CSS. It is unnecessary for the first one as by default, it should be left.

```
​<table style="width:200px;">
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: left;">a</td>
    <td style="text-align: right;">b</td>
</tr>
</table>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```